# insdljs + xetex - newlines ignored, corrupting JavaScript

Tags: xetex

I'm trying to create some dynamic forms in my PDF file with JavaScript.  I am using xelatex to compile it.  Something in the way the `insdljs` package is inserting the JavaScript is making it not work.

Here is a sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{eforms}

\begin{insDLJS}{hello}{Hello, World}
var done=0;

function hello() 
{
    if (!done) {
        // check if we are done
        done=1;
        app.alert("Hello, World!");
    }
}

\end{insDLJS}

\OpenAction{/S /JavaScript /JS (hello();)}
\begin{document}
Hello,world!
\end{document}
```

If you **remove** the useless comment and compile with xelatex, then open the compiled PDF in Acrobat Reader, you get a “Hello, World!” alert.  But with the comment you get no alert.

Looking at the actual JavaScript (you need Acrobat Pro to do this, I think) that gets inserted into the PDF, I see that all the newlines are removed.  It becomes

```
var done=0;function hello(){if (!done) {// check if we are done done=1;app.alert("Hello, World!");}}
```

In JavaScript, the double slash `//` indicates that the rest of the line is a comment.  When all the newlines are stripped, half of the code is ignored!  Acrobat's JavaScript console gives error messages consistent with this (it doesn't find the `}` ending the `hello()` function block).

So here are my workarounds:

1. Use no comments.  Bad Idea.
2. Use only inline comments `/* ... */`  OK, not great.
3. Coerce newlines to appear.  After all, aside from comments, there are probably good reasons to have newlines.

Any ideas on implementing #3?  The [eforms manual](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/acrotex/eformman.pdf) says you can insert newlines with `\n`, but this seems to not be happening.  If I do that I get instead

```
var done=0;function hello(){if (!done) {// check if we are done \ndone=1;app.alert("Hello, World!");}}
```

(the `\n` just went straight into the document level JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

If works if you add a TeX-comment:

```
    %// check if we are done
```

But from the documentation I would have expected that a // works too, so I suggest that you write the author.